# Android Emulator Display Strangely [Virtualbox]

Tags: android, virtualbox, emulation, display

I don't know what's the category of this problem.
But i only encountered this in several apps that runs under my emulator of Android 4.1.1 under VirtualBox.

[image: Display Seems multiplied 4 times...]

Any clue, what should I do to resolve this problem?

Comment: you are running android emulator within virtualbox?  how much RAM do you have?

Comment: everything is fine under my android of 2GB ram, my Windows host is having 8GB in total. But the home screen or other apps is fine. Only several apps show this strange display.